# hidden elements isn't sent in the response - python requests/beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

At hotmails login page, if you expect the HTML code, u can see that there is some hidden fields. If you afterworse view the source code, the hidden fields ain't there anymore.

The problem is I need the values of the hidden fields. And when I requests the HTML from the side as seen below:

```
with requests.session() as c:
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'}
    url = 'https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1482763638&rver=6.4.6456.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fowa%2f&lc=1030&id=292841&mkt=da-dk&cbcxt=out&fl=wld'
    req = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    html = req.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

It takes the HTML of the source code.. which is a problem. Because now I don't get the hidden fields.

What shall I do?

link to hotmail login(for you to check the HTML): https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1482763638&rver=6.4.6456.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fowa%2f&lc=1030&id=292841&mkt=da-dk&cbcxt=out&fl=wld

EDIT: There is one hidden in the source code, but why isn't all the hidden fields in the source code, from the "expect element"?

Here is the hidden fields that doesn't appear in the source code: https://gyazo.com/119fc0fe0c9f242ab705ce0c6affbec9

Comment: Which elements you consider to be `hidden`? Do you mean `iframe`?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/119fc0fe0c9f242ab705ce0c6affbec9

Comment: Here is the source code, where you can see there only is one "hidden" field..?
https://gyazo.com/3144e50976fa34c45de55dff9e19606a

Comment: those input fields could be generated dynamically, so they should not be displayed in initial page source

Comment: You can use `Selenium` to get page source with dynamically generated content. Are you interested in code on `Python` + `Selenium`?

Comment: I moved from selenium to requests, beacuse requests is faster. Isnt it possible without the use of selenium?

Comment: AFAIK `requests` has no possibility to wait until `JavaScript` executed on page

Comment: You can use `PhantomJS` to accelerate `Selenium` script execution

Comment: Can phantomJS be used with python? I have 0 knowledge about javascript

Comment: `PhantomJS` is a headless browser that works faster than common browsers like `Firefox`, `Chrome`... You don't have to know `JavaScript` to use `PhantomJS`